# How do I determine whether $\int _{ -\infty }^{ \infty }{ \frac { x }{ 37+x^2 } dx } $ is convergent or divergent?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Determine whether the integral is convergent or divergent.

$$\int _{ -\infty  }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { x }{ 37+x^2 } dx } $$

---

What I did:

Let $u=37+x^2$, $du=2xdx$

So, we substitute and split the integral to get:

$$\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \int _{ -\infty  }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ u } du } =\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \int _{ -\infty  }^{ 0 }{ \frac { 1 }{ u } du } +\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \int _{ 0 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ u } du } $$

$$\lim _{ t\rightarrow -\infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ 2 } \int _{ t }^{ 0 }{ \frac { 1 }{ u } du }  } +\lim _{ t\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ 2 } \int _{ 0 }^{ t }{ \frac { 1 }{ u } du }  } $$

$$\lim _{ t\rightarrow -\infty  }{ [\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \ln { (37+x^{ 2 }) } ] } _{ t }^{ 0 }+\lim _{ m\rightarrow \infty  }{ [\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \ln { (37+x^{ 2 }) } ] } _{ 0 }^{ m }$$

$$\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \lim _{ t\rightarrow -\infty  }{ [\ln { (37) } -\ln { (37+t^{ 2 }) } ] } +\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \lim _{ m\rightarrow \infty  }{ [\ln { (37+m^{ 2 })-\ln { (37) }  } ] } $$

---

This is as far as I have come. I did attempt to evaluate what will happen at $-\infty$ and $\infty$ by plugging in those values, but the end result did not make sense to me. I would like to know what I need to do to either complete what I have already done, or what I should do if what i have done thus far is wrong.

Comment: When would $u$ go to $-\infty$? That points at something having gone wrong. The substitution is very much ok for calculating the integral over any finite interval, but here we are more interested in dealing with the infinite tails.

Comment: haven't you also got to take the limit as x tends to 0 from both sides?  It isn't defined at zero - it seems it can be evaluated by taking x down to zero though.  Since it's an odd function, the stuff on the negative side is always going to be the negative of the stuff on the positive side, so I think it is zero - in this case - but only because you can take the limit down to zero.

Comment: @AndrewDeighton how is it not defined at $0$? $0$ divided by $37 + 0\cdot 0$ is defined just fine...

Comment: @i'm being stupid, sorry - in that case it's just zero though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted
$$\int_{-t}^{m}\frac{x}{37+x^2} dx=\frac{1}{2}\ln(37+m^{2})-\frac{1}{2}\ln(37+t^{2})=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{37+m^{2}}{37+t^{2}}\right).$$
What happens when  $m=t\to +\infty$?
What happens when  $m=2t\to +\infty$?

Notice that if the integral is convergent, those limits should be equal. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral#Convergence_of_the_integral) for details.

Comment: I see why and how you combined the last part of what I wrote up, but I don't understand what you are trying to point out to me.

Comment: @Cherry_Developer I trying to tell you that those limits (did you calculate them?) are different. This contradicts the definition of convergence of an improper integral (see the link).

Comment: I'm sorry, I just reread the wikipedia link you posted, and I reread what you wrote, but I still do not understand. Why did you make $m=t\to +\infty$?

From what I can tell... it seems that one would go off to negative infinity and the other would go towards positive infinity. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer, Yes. Note that $m=t$ and $m=2t$ are two possible ways to find $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}$, but they give two different answers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your substitutions is **not a bijective function**, so you can't really solve your problem like that. You would have to also replace the bounds of the integration and get a nonsensical expression $\int_\infty^\infty\dots dx$.

To calculate it, you would have to split the integral into two parts on which $37+x^2$ is bijective, so

$$\int_{-\infty}^0 \dots dx + \int_0^\infty\dots dx$$

However, there are also methods you can use to determine the convergence that do not require you to actually calculate the integral.

For example, you may be familiar with the theorem that if $f$ is bounded below by some function which takes the form $$\frac{g(x)}{x^s}$$
where $g(x)>m>0$ for all $x>0$, then the integral $$\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$$
converges if $s>1$ and diverges if $s\leq 1$.

Comment: @AndrewDeighton $$\lim_{a\to-\infty} \int_a^0 f(x)dx + \lim_{b\to\infty}\int_0^b f(x)dx$$ is **not** the same as $$\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_{-b}^b f(x)dx.$$

Comment: that's interesting, but I'm struggling to see why - surely as a and b get larger (not necessarily the same size) the area 'uncancelled' is getting smaller - although saying that, it is forever infinite - hmm, is that the reason?

Comment: @AndrewDeighton The first expression is the sum of two limits. The second is a single limit. If the top two limits exist (by that I mean they are **finite**, then the two expressions are, indeed, the same. But it could be that the top does not exist while the bottom does. And the bottom is not a good way to determine the full integral, because $$\lim_{b\to\infty} \int_{-b}^b f(x)dx \neq \lim_{b\to\infty}\int_{-2b}^b f(x)dx...$$